# Anti-Asian hate crime data

Tags: united-states, data-sources

I am looking for data sources of anti-asian hate crimes that shows percentage of offenders by race e.g. 47% of people who committed hate crimes against Asian Americans were white, 32% were black, etc. (Note that those were just examples) Where can I find such a dataset?

Comment: Come on guys, there was literally no better way I could have asked this question.

Comment: #Ray I voted to reopen, but there is a better way you could have asked this question. You could have shown prior research (or maybe just said “I couldn’t find anything), and maybe given more detail. Also, can you please specify what you mean by “race.” Do you mean country of origin, nationality, race based on what they identify as, etc.

Comment: I've addded a "united states" tag, based on your use of "Asian Americans".  I assume that you are asking about hate crime *in the united states* and not in Europe, Japan, Australia....

Comment: What does this have to do with politics/government? This seems more like a law enforcement issue

Comment: @JoeW I think it’s on topic, if you want I can bring it up on meta (unless it’s already been brought up there)

Comment: @EkadhSingh How does this discuss anything about politics? It is just about crime statistics which shouldn't be political.

Comment: The notion that crime statistics aren't political seems naive to the point of

Comment: Concur with Ekadh & James K stated above. Also, the conflict between the ethnic groups is always used as a weapon in political fighting. It is interesting to know that "the White" is not the only bigot on this matter. I would vote to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crime data is hard.  If you look at police-reported crime you get bias from non-reporting for many reasons.  Sometimes the data only shows the prejudice among the police.

For many crimes, the offender's race isn't recorded, or crimes are miscategorised (for example how do you categorise an attack on a Hindu person from India because they were perceived to be Muslim.)

In the USA, some states have no hate crimes laws at all, so in offical statistics they appear as "zero".  Many hate crimes are committed by unknown offenders.  Racially aggravated graffiti, for example, is hard to investigate and prosecute.

All this is a preamble to the general warning.  Read the reference and not just the headline. The potential for error is very high.

Now, in the American Journal of Criminal Justice there is an article on [Hate Crimes against Asian Americans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7790522/) by
Yan Zhang, Lening Zhang, and Francis Benton.  The authors examined the nature and characteristics of hate crimes against Asian Americans by comparing them with those of hate crimes against African Americans and Hispanics. In their data set there were 329 hate crimes against Asians, of these 245 were committed by white offenders and 84 by non-white offenders.  That is roughly a 75:25 split.  They note that "Comparing with Black and Hispanic victims, Asian Americans also have relatively higher chance to be victimized by non-White offenders."  This finding is then discussed in terms of the “model minority” stereotype. And they build a case that,

> hate crime perpetrators targeting Asian Americans may have very different motives from those targeting African Americans or Hispanics. Whether these motives have to do with their perceptions of fairness, their own identities, or it is merely a thrill-seeking, deserves further examination. Better data need to be collected, and the voices of Asian Americans need to be heard.

Comment: @Ekadh  your edit was harmful because it changed the tone of the quoted article.  I chose where to cut my quote intentionally, please don't change my intention - I'd rather you downvoted.

Comment: How was that section of the quote relevant to the answer in any way?